# How widesread are truck ALS systems today?

Tags: truck, lubrication

Talking specifically about such non-exotic vehicles as long distance semi-trucks, city buses etc., what is the today's de-facto standard with regard to availability of Automatic Lubrication Systems on such vehicles? Do they usually come equipped with ALS from the factory as standard equipment? Or is it optional equipment? Or, maybe, it is usually installed as aftermarket equipment?

Also, is the support/acceptance of ALS different in different parts of the world, like, say, between US and European truck manufacturers?

Answer (score 1):

Trucks had ALS back in 1978 as I was working on them then - I think some were fitted at factory and some aftermarket but the systems were simple and only used for the "easy" nipples...

Comment: OK, but, again, today specifically, is it still a matter of choice? Or are all trucks unconditionally ALS today?

Comment: Given adverts like this - from a simple google search, they are obviously not  all supplied with them but it makes good sense : http://www.jeroindustrial.com/pdf/Auto_Lube_System/TransportationFleets/Global_MORCapabil/Global_MORCapabil.pdf